# Ubuntu terminal, read from console in C but don't print on the screen the text I read

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, terminal, output

I am using Ubuntu and C with VS Code, I want to read text from stdin but after I am done reading I don't want the text I read to appear on the screen/terminal.
Also I want to see the letters that I am reading but after I am done, I don't want to see the string on the screen.

I have used the code below but I am not getting the results I want as I want to see the characters that I am reading:

```
    /* get terminal attributes */
    struct termios termios;
    tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO, &termios);

    /* disable echo */
    termios.c_lflag &= ~ECHO;
    tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSAFLUSH, &termios);
```

Comment: If you try passing `TCSANOW` instead of `TCSAFLUSH`, does it change anything?

Comment: Also, what happens with the code you show? Can you please try to create a proper [mre] to show us? What are the actual "results" you get? And what are the expected "results" you want?

Comment: Do you mean you want to _erase_ the input from the terminal screen after a few seconds? Please edit the question and try to be more clear about your program "_reading_ the text" and your eyeballs "_reading_ the text"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To rephrase your purpose, you want the input to be erased after you hit the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

You can do this using ANSI escape sequences. Here is an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char phrase[100];

    printf("Enter passphrase: ");
    if (!fgets(phrase, sizeof phrase, stdin))
        return 1;
    phrase[strcspn(phrase, "\n")] = '\0'; // strip the newline if any

    printf("\033[F\r");   // back up one line
    printf("Enter passphrase: "); // output the prompt on top of itself
    printf("\033[K\r\n"); // erase end of line, move to next line

    printf("\nPass phrase is %s\n", phrase);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! This is what i needed and sorry for the headache i gave you.